# question about the different definitions for Green's function for many-body problems

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

I have met two kinds of definitions for [Green's function for many-body problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function_(many-body_theory)) in condensed matter physics:

[1. The version I:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019922725X)

$$iG(x_b,t_b,x_a,t_a)\equiv \left<x_b|U(t_b,t_a)|x_a\right>$$

where $U(t_b,t_a)$ is the time evolution operator.

2. [The Version II:](http://folk.ntnu.no/johnof/green-2013.pdf)
   $$G^R(x,t;x^\prime,t^\prime) \equiv -i\theta(t-t^\prime)\left<[\psi(x,t),\psi^\dagger(x^\prime,t^\prime)]_{\pm}\right>$$

where $\psi(x,t) (\psi^\dagger(x^\prime,t^\prime)))$ is the annihilation (creation) operator.The upper sign is for fermions and the lower sign is for bosons.

> Q: What are the difference and relations between the two different definitions?

Comment: The first one is one definition of the Green's function in quantum mechanics, the second one is one definition of the *retarded* Green's function in quantum field theory, the reason why there is the Heaviside step function in front of it. Anyways, when written with some time-evolution operator $U$, the Green's function is usually about quantum mechanics (version I). When it's written with some second quantised operators (as I assume $\psi$ is), the Green's function is usually about quantum field problems (version II).

Comment: @FraSchelle I think this should be an answer.